# Propagate TypeScript type from one type definition to others

Tags: typescript

This question is derived from using TypeScript libraries whose type definitions are too strict, in my opinion. For example, I have used a couple that forces developers to use string or numeric User IDs (depending on the database, there are conversions for both) but I think there should be a way to support both.

The problem(s) boil down to trying to allow developers to choose the type of User ID that aligns with their stack. I've changed it from:

```
type User = {
    id: string;
}
```

to:

```
type User<UserIdType = string> = {
    id: UserIdType;
}
```

This somewhat works and any types that extend or use User, as long as they don't overwrite id will keep the type definition. The problem is that there are other type definitions that have `userId: string;` hardcoded and I can't figure out how to allow userId to retain the same type as defined on User. I've tried many different solutions, searched the TypScript documentation, even asked ChatGPT (which fails pretty hard at TypeScript) with no luck. Some things I was trying to use but didn't expect to work were `ReturnType<>` and `typeof`.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like this:

```
type User<UserIdType = string> = {
    id: UserIdType;
}
type AnotherType = {
    userId: UserIdType; // I know I can't do this
}
```

or:

```
type User<T = string> = {
    id: T;
}
type UserIdType = getType(User.id); // this doesn't work and can't use typeof for obvious reasons
type AnotherType = {
    userId: UserIdType;
}
```

I'd prefer if the type was defined in one location and propagated to other types that are supposed to reference the original value rather than resorting to explicitly state it everywhere and keep them in sync (that seems overly cumbersome) like this:

```
type AnotherType<UserIdType = string> = {
    userId: UserIdType;
}
```

Comment: You could write `User["id"]` but that is always `string`.  Presumably you want a type that will "dynamically" change somehow?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, ideally the types would allow developers to type `User<number>` if they are following a numeric MySQL auto-incrementing `id` convention and `User<string>`, or just `User` if it defaults to type `string`, if they are using Mongo or others where strings are used for `id`.

Comment: How about a module that lets importing codebases override the type?  Like, [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-n9hxj7?file=/index.ts) would be the "basic" version where `UserIdType` is `string`, and code that wants to do something else would use module augmentation as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-x5n4m6?file=/index.ts)?  This takes generics out of the picture.  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that TypeScript but would someone have to overwrite `OverrideUserIdType` to be able to change the type for the User.id? I don't think that's the worst idea as that's similar to the workaround I've been doing but I was hoping there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: If by “overwrite” you mean modify the files of your library, no.  They would use declaration merging in their own code to add a property to an interface exported by your library.  As shown in the link in my previous comment.